# spring security login: Validating input

Tags: spring-security, bean-validation

I am looking for a sound method of performing input validation for the user credentials on login. Specifically - that the username conforms to some size limit: if provided value is too big, fail fast, instead of passing it through to the `userDetailsService`.

A somewhat crude solution is to explicitly test this condition at the gate, in the `userDetailsService`:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if (username.length() > MAX_USERNAME_LEN )
            throw new BadCredentialsException("username too long");
            //...
    }
}
```

From a domain model perspective, the size limit can be expressed as a validation constraint (`@Size(max = ...)`) on the user entity. Since username is a request parameter, request validation (`@Valid`) also seems like a possible direction. But I am not sure how to leverage those mechanisms in the current setup.

Can someone provide some guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable bean validation support by registering `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` and `MethodValidationPostProcessor` first. (Refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring) for the details). If you are using spring-boot , its auto-configuration should already configure them for you.

After that , you can validate the method parameters by using `@Validated` and `@Size`:

```java
@Service
@Validated
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(@Size(max = MAX_USERNAME_LEN) String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `loadUserByUsername` is overriden, so the above produces a `javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: Only the root method of an overridden method in an inheritance hierarchy may be annotated with parameter constraints.` Adding a delegate makes this a less attractive solution. Also, It triggers an http 500. My original solution, raising a `BadCredentialsException`, redirects to the auth error page - preferable over an internal server error.